# Suppressed Data being calculated on a count

Tags: crystal-reports, db2, crystal-reports-xi

[image]I am trying to get a count of records for a the `Charge Group`; however it is counting my suppressed data as well. I understand that suppressed data is only hidden and doesn't effect any calculation, but how can I adjust my formula so it doesn't take the suppressed data.

I attempted to do a running total field however I receive an error

```
A running total cannot refer to a print time formula Details: @Customer Drop Max Amount
```

Within the report there are multiple `Trailer Charge Groups` that are basically shippers and their destinations are marked as `Drop Customers`

I only want one record for two `Drop Customers` to be computed, so whenever another trailer falls into the record for `Drop Customer` I have to change the count field to show that their should only be one.

The formula field I am doing that for is `Charge group count`

```
IF {@TRAILER CHARGE GROUP} = 'INTCNEWNC' THEN Count ({TRAILER_CUSTOMER_ZONE.TRAILER_ID} , {@TRAILER CHARGE GROUP}) - 6
ELSE IF {@TRAILER CHARGE GROUP} <> 'INTCNEWNC' THEN Count ({TRAILER_CUSTOMER_ZONE.TRAILER_ID}, {@TRAILER CHARGE GROUP} )
```

I am using Crystal Reports XI on a DB2 server.

Thanks in advance!

edit: INTCNEWNC is the charge group, whereas ASHLADVNC and MARSBIVA are the drop customers. You can clearly see the individual counts for Drop customers are fine but the count for charge groups is where I am struggling.

Comment: I think we need to see the whole statement, and probably sample starting data and desired output.  Note that two-argument `COUNT` isn't available "by default" on DB2, which would normally do this with a `GROUP BY` (or possibly a window function - what version of DB2 are you using?).  You also don't need to wrap the `COUNT` in the `IF` - just the final addition.

Comment: you have to pass to that counter your suppress condition as well

Comment: @Siva basically I am asking whether I can make the count for the specific Charge group something like count of trailers - count of trailers for drop customer 1 - count of trailers for drop customer 2 + 2 (because they are suppose to only have one trailer on the report) whereas the other drop customers can vary based off of when the report is ran and where the trailer pinged.

Comment: @cojimarmiami I have a counter statement to calculate the customer max drop amount.

Comment: include on that counter statement the suppress condition that is hiding your suppressed data, even though that data doesn't show on the report, it will be counted unless you exclude it

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I attached an image, with additionally details hopefully this helps.

Comment: @cojimarmiami okay, I'll give it a try and I'll let you know thank yoU!

Comment: @cojimarmiami oddly enought I cant insert the count (running total fields) in my report.... secondly the count is being done by a formula field charge group count

Comment: @cojimarmiami I gave it a try on my other copy of the report and it crashed my report...

Comment: are you doing a running total based on a database field or a formula?

Comment: @cojimarmiami Formula as listed above as Charge group count, I figured something like this should work but I don't know how to write it... IF {@TRAILER CHARGE GROUP} = 'INTCNEWNC' THEN Count ({TRAILER_CUSTOMER_ZONE.TRAILER_ID}  - COUNT OF ASHLEY FURNITURE – COUNT OF MARSBRIVA + 2 
ELSE IF {@TRAILER CHARGE GROUP} <> 'INTCNEWNC' THEN Count ({TRAILER_CUSTOMER_ZONE.TRAILER_ID}, {@TRAILER CHARGE GROUP} )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103107/discussion-between-cojimarmiami-and-ovo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create running total fields for both the specific drop customer and charge group.
2) A formula field stating 
IF CHARGEGROUP = 'MY CHARGE GROUP' then (rt.charge group) - (rt.drop customer 1) - (rt.drop customer 2) + 2 else count(trailer)